# How to disable touchscreen via Xwayland on Dell Inspiron 15 5000 Series running Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: linux, ubuntu, touchscreen

I have a Dell Inspiron 15 5000 Series laptop running Ubuntu 20.04. This laptop has touchscreen functionality which I want to permanently disable. I tried the following:

```
xinput --list

WARNING: running xinput against an Xwayland server. See the xinput man page for details.
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ xwayland-pointer:17                       id=6    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ xwayland-relative-pointer:17              id=7    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ xwayland-touch:17                         id=9    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ xwayland-keyboard:17                      id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

I tried to disable xwayland-touch:17 via the command:

```
xinput disable 9
```

And got:

```
WARNING: running xinput against an Xwayland server. See the xinput man page for details.
```

I read the section "XWAYLAND" in the man page for xinput but am still not sure how I can permanently disable the touchscreen.

Can anyone please help with this?

Comment: Got the same issue on a Sony Vaio running Fedora 35. Zero information on this to be found anywhere.